# Program cannot run OpenCV even though others can

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, opencv

I am trying to run a program that uses OpenCV and I have gotten it to run on other machines, and other programs on my machine run using it, but this one returns:

```
programname.cpp:  fatal error: opencv/cv.h: No such file or directory
```

Anyone know how to fix the path or what might be going wrong?  I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and OpenCV-2.4.0

Comment: Which IDE are you using, or are you compiling in the terminal?

Comment: I am compiling using the terminal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 11.04, the headers are in: `*/usr/include/opencv-2.3.1/*`, I assume it should be `*/usr/include/opencv-2.4.0/*` for you.

You have two solutions:

- When you compile, use the `-I` option: `g++ -o [name] [src] -I/usr/include/opencv-2.4.0`
- Create symbolic links to *opencv-2.4.0/opencv* and *opencv-2.4.0/opencv2* in */usr/include*.

The second solution is useful if you're using CMake, because FindOpenCV2 does not look for OpenCV in `/usr/include/opencv-2.4.0`. I hope this (ugly) hack will solve your problem.

Comment: so that seemingly worked in that the program now runs but the program was supposed to modify an image's color and it is coming out all black now.  is there any way this could have missed some files or corrupted some?

Comment: okay I just got it.  thanks so much for the help. making symbolic links solved it for me

Answer (score 11):

Change from:

`#include <opencv/cv.h>`

to:

`#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`